# How to return city name as value instead of id?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have just wrote a code of datalist of city name which will find city from given state id. But while selecting the city name it is showing state id too and after select it is showing only state id instead of displaying city name.
Here is the code.

```
  <?php
    echo '<input type="text" list="city" class="form-control" />
                <datalist id="city" >';
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db("placedb",$con);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE state_id BETWEEN 1 AND 41 ORDER BY name ASC ") or die(mysql_error());

    $items = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $items[] = $row;
    } 

    foreach($items as $item){

        printf('<option id="city" value="%s">%s</option>', $item['id'], $item['name']);
    }
    echo '</datalist>';

    ?>
```

Comment: Remove `$item['id']` I guess? If you've just written this surely you'd know that. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Seems like a copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use   `$item['name']` instead of `$item['id']`

Answer (score 0):

I think the printf should be

```
printf('<option id="city" value="%d">%s</option>', $item['id'], $item['name']);
```